# The calendar of primefaces doesn't work

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I deploy the showcase of primefaces under glassfish. When I open the page of Calendar. There is something wrong.

### [image]

[image]
--------------Following is my code, I think there is nothing wrong-------------

```
 <p:calendar value="#{unSubmitConsign.startDate}" 
                       selectListener="#{unSubmitConsign.handleDateSelect}" />

@ManagedBean(name = "unSubmitConsign")
@SessionScoped
public class UnSubmitManagedBean {
   public Date getStartDate() {
      return startDate;
   }

   public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
      System.out.println("setStartDate:" + startDate);
      this.startDate = startDate;
   }

   private Date startDate;

   public void handleDateSelect(DateSelectEvent event) {
      SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
      Date date = event.getDate();
      String s = format.format(date);
      System.out.println("::::::"+s);
   }
}
```

It prints nothing........

Comment: The 2nd screenshot has several same error messages. But I can't decipher Chinese and I can't copypaste from a picture into Google Translate ... Can you translate it to English?

Comment: That means, "There are something wrong when convert the input String to a Date instance." I know what's wrong. If I use the property pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" for calendar, there will be right. Because if I don't assign a pattern, it will use the default pattern which maybe like this "mm-dd-yyyy".